# Model decorator in rails-5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, decorator

In rails 4 I have following decorator code. That was working well

```
app/decorators/models/user_decorator.rb

User.class_eval do
  devise :omniauthable
end
```

Now I am upgrading rails to version 5. But its giving me error

> Mapping omniauth_callbacks on a resource that is not omniauthable
>   Please add `devise :omniauthable` to the `User` model

All of my models are in separate gem and I do not have devise installed in that gem. That is why I am using above decorator to add devise in my application. 
How can I achieve same functionality in rails-5?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a Concern to decorate the user model with devise :omniauthable. The reason why class_eval doesn't work is not apparent from the background you provided. It might have something to do with rails internal magic which may have changed from rails 4 to 5, so using a Concern which is the "rails way" of adding behaviour to a Model might solve your problem.

```
module OmniauthableUser

  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do 
    devise :omniauthable
  end

end


app/decorators/models/user_decorator.rb

User.include OmniauthableUser
```